# How do I solve the following integral(absolute value)

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-1}^1(1+2x^{2015})e^{-\lvert x \rvert }df $$
I tried splitting the integrals from -1 to 0 and 0 to 1 but it won't work

Comment: You can notice the interval is symmetric and then investigate which parts of the function are even and which are odd.

Comment: It's kind of complicated to integrate by parts since I have $x^{2015}$

Comment: And I noticed the interval is symmetric but I don't know how to solve it after that. Do I still need to split it?

Comment: The term $x^{2015} = - (-x)^{2015}$ is odd. So for each positive x, then -x gives the opposite contribution to the integral which means if the interval is symmetric around $x=0$ then the term vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1(1+2x^{2015})e^{-\lvert x \rvert }dx
\
&= \int_{-1}^1e^{-\lvert x \rvert }dx + 2\int_{-1}^1x^{2015}e^{-\lvert x \rvert }dx
\
= \int_{-1}^1e^{-\lvert x \rvert }dx
\
= 2(1-e^{-1})
\end{align}

The vanishing integral has odd symmetry. The remaining integral has even symmetry, which you'd want to take advantage of to fill in the last step.

Comment: I wanted to solve it using the fact that the interval is centered in $0$ but I forgot that if its odd then its 0 and if its even its 2 x the integral,have to blame my memory for that,thank you :)

Comment: @Lola Plot an even function (e.g. $x^2$) and an odd function (e.g. $x^3$). Can you see why the even integrals are equal to twice half the range of integration and why odd integrals vanish? Note that even functions have reflection symmetry about the y-axis, while odd functions have 2-fold rotational symmetry about the origin.